# Sql date and time comparison from dual table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns state_date and state_time

I want to pull records from database using columns state_date and state_time.State_date and state_time are should  less than or equals to below sql.Below sql giving date and time.But i have individual columns one is having date and other is having time.SO first i want to compare date and after that time.How can i modify below query to get date and time seperately with milli seconds.

```
select decode(TRIM(to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')),'Monday','3','1') from dual
```

Sample Data:

order table:

```
order id   order name  order date
1          pizza       20-feb-2012
2          burger      17-feb-2012
```

order_state table

```
order id     order_state     order_date                order_time
1             initiated      20-feb-2012               12:29:11:203
1             processed      21-feb-2012               12:29:12:112
1             cancelled      21-feb-2012               12:29:11:311
```

So here i want to fetch the latest record i.e cancelled based on order_date and order_time ,order_id and today date.if i query today at 12:29:10:311 or 12:29:11:310.i want to fetch the cancelled record.

Thanks,

Chaitu

Comment: What data types are `STATE_DATE` and `STATE_TIME`?  If they are DATE columns, I'm confused because an Oracle DATE always has both a day component and a time component.

Comment: You seem to be after the Day of the week. You want this and milliseconds?

Comment: @Ben: I want to consider even milli seconds

Comment: @Justin: Here state_date is the date type Date,whereas state_time is the type of varchar2

Comment: @user569125 - OK.  So then `STATE_DATE` has a time component.  What do you want to do with the time component of `STATE_DATE`?  What is the purpose of having a separate `STATE_TIME` column if that column is just duplicating data that is already in `STATE_DATE`?

Comment: state_date not storing acutual time.state_time is storing the  exact time.

Comment: @user569125, I've just given you some sort of answer, but your query above indicates `state_time` is either a string or a number, not a date.

Comment: any help on this friends.provided example data.

Comment: Creating new thread for this question,not getting any good answers

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I've got you. You want to do the following?

```
select <columns>
  from my_table
 where state_date <= <some date>
   and state_time <= <some time>
```

It's fairly unusual to care about the milliseconds but if you do then you should use `systimestamp`.

Judging by the fact you've split date and time, these are characters, So, I'm going to have to guess the [format masks](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-fmt.html). If they're wrong the link should guide you on what to do. It's not wise, by the way, to split a date in this way. You could create a column using the `timestamp` data-type in your table, which would make your problem extremely simple.

So, I don't know why you've chosen the `'Day'` format for your query but going with that `<some date>` becomes `to_char(sysdate, 'DAY')`.

---

From your comment below `<some date>` would be `to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY')`

---

`<some time>` would be `to_char(systimestamp,'HH24:MI:SS:FF3')`, which would give you the timestamp to the millisecond, though the datatype can go to the micro-second.

It seems a little strange to me but your query would then become:

```
select <columns>
  from my_table
 where state_date <= to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY')
   and state_time <= to_char(systimestamp,'HH24:MI:SS:FF3')
```

It would be more normal, if storing a date as a string, to store it in the format `yyyymmdd` so at least you can guarantee it's in order. If you've done something like this then just change the format mask. If you haven't then these queries aren't going to work as intended.

---

Personally, if you **have** to store data this way and assuming `state_date` is stored as, say, `dd-mon-yy`, i.e. including year, month AND day, and `state_time` is stored as indicated above, then I would do something like this:

```
select <columns>
  from my_table
 where to_timestamp(state_date || state_time, 'DD-MON-YYHH24:MI:SS:FF3')
        <= systimestamp
```

It makes it a lot more obvious what is going on and there is no ambiguity on what `<` means in this situation as a date will always be less than a future date, which doesn't necessarily hold true for strings.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: getting error saying the input data to be converted using date model was incorrect.and i also want this to be performed atleast for date decode(TRIM(to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')),'Monday','3','1')

Comment: State_date :11-SEP-09 ,state_time: 17:10:23:812

Comment: i think you did n't consider decode(TRIM(to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')),'Monday','3','1') .here idea is,today is tuesday so it returns 1,i am deducting from today date ,so it will give monday date.So i have to display records from yesterday to today.

Comment: @user569125, you didn't mention any of this in your question. However, this is just an addition `and` in the queries above, so should be easy to add using the information provided.

Comment: :Could you please ammend the above query to retrieve cancelled record as per example i provided.