# Retrieving data from db based on system date and time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Could you please advice or provide any solution ,how to solve the below problem:

**order table:**

```
order id   order_name  order_date
1          pizza       20-feb-2012
2          burger      17-feb-2012
```

**order_state table**

```
order_id     order_state     order_state_date          order_state_time
1             initiated      20-feb-2012               12:29:11:203
1             processed      21-feb-2012               12:29:12:112
1             cancelled      21-feb-2012               12:29:11:311
2             initiated      17-feb-2012               12:11:10:201
2             processed      18-feb-2012               12:01:01:301
2             cancelled      19-feb-2012               12:29:59:300
```

if i query on monday ,i have to check last 3 days i.e friday,saturday and sunday.So that i able to fetch second record,if i query today ,i able to fetch first recrod ,in both cases cancelled record i should able to fetch based on data and time.

Below Sql gives the system date and time based on day:

```
select decode(TRIM(to_char(SYSDATE,'Day')),'Monday','3','1') from dual
```

Result,if i query on monday at 12:30 P.M or 12:29:59:299

```
order_id   order_state    order_name  order_state_date   order_state_time

2          canceled       burger      19-feb-2012         12:29:59:300
```

Result,if i query today at 12:29:10:311 P.M

```
order_id   order_state    order_name  order_state_date   order_state_time

    1          canceled       pizza      21-feb-2012         12:29:59:300
```

Thanks,

Chaitu

Comment: What are the expected results of your query ?

Comment: question updated,added expected result

Comment: Don't create [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385877) - please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty). If you don't get suitable answers, improve the original question to explain what you need.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to follow exactly what you're after, and your data and results seem to be contradictory in places; I think you want to use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407) to pull the latest state of each order, but only if the last change to the order was in the last three days - down to millisecond precision?

Using CTEs to generate your sample data:

```
with orders as (
select 1 as order_id, 'pizza' as order_name, '20-feb-2012' as order_date
    from dual
union all select 2, 'burger', '17-feb-2012' from dual
),
order_state as (
select 1 as order_id, 'initiated' as order_state, '20-feb-2012' as
    order_state_date, '12:29:11:203' as order_state_time from dual
union all select 1, 'processed', '21-feb-2012', '12:29:12:112' from dual
union all select 1, 'cancelled', '21-feb-2012', '12:29:11:311' from dual
union all select 2, 'initiated', '17-feb-2012', '12:11:10:201' from dual
union all select 2, 'processed', '18-feb-2012', '12:01:01:301' from dual
union all select 2, 'cancelled', '19-feb-2012', '12:29:59:300' from dual
)
-- actual query starts here
select order_id, order_state, order_state_date, order_state_time
from (
    select o.order_id,
        first_value(os.order_state)
            over (partition by os.order_id
                order by os.order_state_timestamp desc) as order_state,
        to_char(max(os.order_state_timestamp) over (partition by os.order_id),
            'DD-mon-YYYY') as order_state_date,
        to_char(max(os.order_state_timestamp) over (partition by os.order_id),
            'HH24:MI:SS:FF3') as order_state_time,
        max(os.order_state_timestamp) over (partition by os.order_id)
            as last_order_state_timestamp,
        row_number() over (partition by os.order_id order by os.order_id) as rn
    from orders o
    join (select order_id, order_state,
        to_timestamp(order_state_date ||' '|| order_state_time,
            'DD-mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3') as order_state_timestamp
        from order_state) os
    on os.order_id = o.order_id
)
where rn = 1
and last_order_state_timestamp > systimestamp - interval '3' day;

  ORDER_ID ORDER_STA ORDER_STATE_DATE     ORDER_STATE_TIME
---------- --------- -------------------- ------------------
         1 processed 21-feb-2012          12:29:12:112
```

Your expected results have `cancelled`, but the date/time values for the states look the wrong way round.

If you want to show orders created in the last three days, not just those updated, then you'll need to get the `min()` instead of `max()` timestamp and filter on that.

---

*You don't seem to be interested in fixing the model to use proper date/timestamp column types, so this is apparently not relevant...*

Storing the date and time in separate fields is making this much harder than it needs to be, and I can't think of any valid reason to do that. If it's only done because a [`DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref154) field doesn't hold milliseconds, then use a [`TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref159) field instead. I've tried to minimise the pain by converting it on the fly in the subquery, but it's still not a good model. If you had a single `order_state_timestamp` field instead of the separate date/time fields, the query could be something like:

```
select order_id, order_state,
    to_char(last_order_state_timestamp, 'DD-mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')
    as order_state_timestamp
from (
    select o.order_id,
        first_value(os.order_state)
            over (partition by os.order_id
                order by os.order_state_timestamp desc) as order_state,
        max(os.order_state_timestamp) over (partition by os.order_id)
            as last_order_state_timestamp,
        row_number() over (partition by os.order_id order by os.order_id) as rn
    from orders o
    join order_state os on os.order_id = o.order_id
)
where rn = 1
and last_order_state_timestamp > systimestamp - interval '3' day;
```

which is slightly less unpleasant.

---

**Edit:** Based on a comment on your [previous/duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385877), you want the number of days you look back to vary depending on the current day. That isn't at all obvious from either question. You can do that with:

```
and last_order_state_timestamp > systimestamp
    - numtodsinterval(decode(to_char(sysdate, 'D'), '1', 3, 1), 'DAY');
```

But you need to be careful with your NLS settings; the result of `to_char(sysdate, 'D')` is `1` on Monday here, but may be `0` or something else where you are. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#sthref395), particularly the comment against the `D` element.

Comment: what is last_order_state_timestamp?.could you please simplify the answer.

Comment: In the first query it's a temporary column formed in the subquery, to make it easier to do the ordering in the analytic functions. In the second I'm hoping you're changed the model so your `order_state` table has columns `order_id, order_state, order_state_timestamp` instead of separate date and time columns. If the answer doesn't help you, amend your question to clarify what you need.

Comment: model not changed,still they are seperate columns

Comment: even your first query not giving proper result,it should give this record 1, 'cancelled', '21-feb-2012', '12:29:11:311'.because if you see 311 micro seconds is the latest record

Comment: @user569125 - no, because the time in your third record, `12:29:**11:311**`, is *earlier* than your second, `12:29:**12:112**`. I said in the answer that your data looked wrong; the cancelled is before the processed.

Comment: your right Alex,sorry about this.is it anyway to optimize the first answer.second approach not suitable to me.Is it possible to do without analytical functions.

Comment: and also order_state_time is not the type of timestamp,actually it is varchar2